# Possible memory leak with mem::swap in tokio routine

Tags: rust, memory-leaks

The process will killed by OOM, it seems memory can't be released in somewhere, where does the problem arise?  static, routine or mem::swap? Or should I solve it.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

use std::mem;
use std::sync::Arc;
use parking_lot::Mutex;

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref Buffer: Arc<Mutex<Vec<i64>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::with_capacity(100)));
}

pub async fn consume() {
    let mut lk = Buffer.lock();
    lk.clear();
    drop(lk);
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut vec: Vec<i64> = Vec::with_capacity(100);
    loop {
        vec.push(1);
        if vec.len() == 100 {
            let mut lk = Buffer.lock();
            mem::swap(&mut vec, &mut *lk);
            drop(lk);
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                consume().await
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you mean, the task won't release its memory after it's finished?

Comment: nevermind, that wasn't that, you grow your vec at infinite. BTW, you mixing sync api with async api, you should use tokio mutex.

Comment: @Stargateur [Not necessarily](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html#which-kind-of-mutex-should-you-use). Async mutexes are only really necessary when the lock needs to be held across an await point.

Comment: @apilat I have no idea who write that but it's look **completely wrong**, everywhere in the doc of tokio it's clearly state that async task **should not block** and here in the doc you have a line that say it's ok ? that look very very very wrong, the doc itself seem to contract itself "Note that, although the compiler will not prevent the std Mutex from holding its guard across .await points in situations where the task is not movable between threads, this virtually never leads to correct concurrent code in practice as it can easily lead to deadlocks." I would triple check this doc

Comment: @Stargateur That sounds like dogmatic thinking; "locking a mutex" and "blocking" are not synonymous. If you are in a situation where locking your mutex means you're likely going to block, then yes you should use an async mutex to be friendly to the executor. But most uses of mutexes use small critical sections and aren't contentious, and thus even if they do block, it will more than likely be no more impactful than a context-switch that your OS thread scheduler is imposing every few milliseconds anyway. As always, context is important.

Comment: @kmdreko I open an issue for that https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/5024 I still think the current doc is very misleading. I would just not recommend to use mutex as normal user of async. A newbie would fall into trap faster than sonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you expect this code to do (please correct me if this is wrong):

1. `vec` is filled up to 100 elements and put into buffer.
2. while it is being filled up again, the background task frees the buffer.
3. rinse and repeat.

But consider what happens when your main loop managed to acquire the lock twice in a row: then the task didn't have time to clear the buffer and after the `mem::swap` call, the `vec` still has 100 elements.
From this point on, `vec.len() == 100` will never be true and your code simply appends to the vector in a loop.
Note that this only needs to happen once and then your code never recovers.

The fix to this is to, instead of only trying to clear the vector when it has exactly 100 elements, do so whenever it has *at least* 100 elements:

```
if vec.len() >= 100 {
```